# Why won't mysql-client connect to the GCP cloud_sql_proxy via a docker-forwarded tcp port?

Tags: mysql, docker, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

## The Gist

I have an application that wants to connect to a mysql database via a tcp port.  I'm building a docker container which stages cloud sql instances for it to connect to (the databases contain test cases imported from elsewhere).  I expect to be able to forward the mysql port from inside of the docker container and connect from outside of the container, but I get an error.

## What I Have Tried

#### Database in the container, this works

When I have a database in a local container, I can connect like this:

```
# run in background, listening on port 13306
❯ docker run -p 13306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test -d percona:5.7.26-centos
    9c25...

❯ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P13306 -uroot -ptest
    mysql> --connection successful
```

#### Proxy in the container (connect from without), this doesn't work

But when I have the cloud_sql_proxy in a local container, I get this error:

```
# run in background, listening on port 13306
❯ docker run -p 13306:3306 \
         -v "${PWD}/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud" \
         -d portforwardexample \
         cloud_sql_proxy "-instances=myproject:us-west2:myinstance=tcp:3306"
      d56c...

❯ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P13306
    ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

If I stop the container, I get a different message:

```
❯ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P13306
    ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

...so I know that *some* communication is happening.

#### Proxy in the container (connect from within), this works

I know that the problem is on my end because everything works as expected when I use an interactive session and connect from within the container.

```
❯ docker run -it --rm -p 13306:3306 \
         -v "${PWD}/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud" \
         portforwardexample
root@bcf:/# cloud_sql_proxy "-instances=myproject:us-west2:myinstance=tcp:3306" &
2019/12/14 22:44:04 Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for myproject:us-west2:myinstance
2019/12/14 22:44:04 Ready for new connections

root@bcf:/# mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P3306
mysql>  --connection successful
```

Why can't I connect from outside of the container?  Is there something that I need to do to tell the container that it's OK to forward the port via docker?

I've omitted details that I don't think are relevant to my issue, but here's a repo that contains a few extra details (like the Dockerfile I'm using): https://github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/cloudsqlproxyproblem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a program inside a container says `Listening on 127.0.0.1` it will probably be unreachable from outside the container, and you need to somehow configure it so it binds or listens to 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces) instead.

The example in [the Cloud SQL Proxy documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-docker#connect-client) has this option:

```
/cloud_sql_proxy -instances=...=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306 ...
```

and that 0.0.0.0 is the important one.

Comment: Oh man, I don't know how I overlooked that, it's right there in the docs.  I had hacked together something involving `socat` that kind of worked, but this is much better.  Thank you.